# WPF CheckBox style with the TextWrapping

Tags: wpf, checkbox, styles, alignment, word-wrap

I need to apply a `TextWrapping` in the WPF `CheckBox`.

Please look at this two samples:

```
<CheckBox>  
  <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap"  
             Text="_This is a long piece of text attached to a checkbox."/>  
</CheckBox>

<CheckBox>  
  <AccessText TextWrapping="Wrap"  
              Text="_This is a long piece of text attached to a checkbox."/>  
</CheckBox>
```

If I use a `TextBlock` in the `Content` of the `CheckBox`, the check element (vertical alignment is top) and the text displays properly, but not the accelerator.

[image]

If I use an `AccessText` in the `Content` of the `CheckBox`, the check element displays wrong  (vertical alignment is center).

How can I change the `Style` of the elements to display this `CheckBox` correct?

Comment: One man's garbage is another man's treasure. I wanted to figure out how to make my check element vertically centered with respect to the text, because VerticalAlignment and VerticalContentAlignment don't help. Answer: I just have to use AccessText instead of TextBlock! +1 for the tip :)

Comment: You're welcome. But my question here remains...

Answer (score 18):

If you combine the two you will probably get the effect you desire.

```
<CheckBox>
    <TextBlock>
        <AccessText TextWrapping="Wrap"  
                    Text="_This is a long piece of text attached to a checkbox."/>  
    </TextBlock>
</CheckBox>
```

Comment: I have tried, it doesn't work. You can try it very fast using e.g the XamlPad.

Answer (score 1):

Use **VerticalContentAlignment** to align the box to the top. Use **Padding** to adjust text position.

```
<CheckBox VerticalContentAlignment="Top" Padding="2,-2,0,0">
    <AccessText Text="_This is a long piece of text attached to a checkbox." TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
</CheckBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Havew you tried setting an implicit style for the AccessText, or just an AccessText style you can apply?

Here's an implicit style that would work:

```
    <Style x:Key="{x:Type AccessText}" 
    TargetType="{x:Type AccessText}"
    BasedOn="{x:Null}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
    <Setter Property="TextTrimming" Value="CharacterEllipsis"/>
    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="NoWrap"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,2"/>
    <Setter Property="Text" Value="AccessText"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

If you include this in your project the AccessText should work the way you want. If you need something else, adjust the style.

If you don't want all AccessTexts to behave this way, name the style and apply it where you use it:

```
<CheckBox>         
  <AccessText TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{DynamicResource CkbxAccessTextStyle}"        
              Text="_This is a long piece of text attached to a checkbox."/>         
</CheckBox>
```

Comment: Unfortunally <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/> didn't work like with the TextBlock.